# SqlNotificationEvent notify multiple times for even single insert in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, sqlcachedependency

`SqlNotificationEvent` notify multiple times for even single insert in database.

Even for single insert/update/delete in table the event notify for several time with `e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change`, can anyone help why this happens. It should notify only once for single change in table.

```
static class Program
{
    private static string mStarterConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Database=SqlDependencyTest;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=startUser;Password=startUser";
    private static string mSubscriberConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Database=SqlDependencyTest;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=subscribeUser;Password=subscribeUser";
    public const string CACHE_KEY = "APPCACHEKEY";

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Starting the listener infrastructure...
        SqlDependency.Start(mStarterConnectionString);

        // Registering for changes... 
        RegisterForChanges();

        Application.Run(new SqlCache());

        // Quitting...
        SqlDependency.Stop(mStarterConnectionString);
    }

    public static DataTable RegisterForChanges()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        // Connecting to the database using our subscriber connection string and
        // waiting for changes...
        SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(mSubscriberConnectionString);
        oConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetUsers", oConnection))
            //using (SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.Users", oConnection))
            {
                oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDependency oDependency = new SqlDependency(oCommand);
                oDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnNotificationChange);
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oCommand))
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }

            AppMain.Cache.Insert(CACHE_KEY, dataTable, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
        finally
        {
            oConnection.Close();
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    public static void OnNotificationChange(object caller, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            RegisterForChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlNotificationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.aspx) object's [SqlNotificationInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo.aspx) object and check whether it is Insert, Update or Delete and ignore the rest.

```
public static void OnNotificationChange(object caller, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change && (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Delete || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update))
    {
        SqlDependency dependency =(SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= OnNotificationChange;
        RegisterForChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: public static void OnNotificationChange(object caller, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) { if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change && (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Delete || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update)) RegisterForChanges(); } I have done above changes, actually e.Type shows "Change" and e.Info shows "Insert", for several times when insert one row in table. Please me if any one knows this problem.

Comment: @Shivu Answer Updated. Please check

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue as described in the question.  I was able to pinpoint that the issue resulted from creating multiple `SqlCommand` instances (similar to how you have `using (SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetUsers", oConnection))` inside `RegisterForChanges()`.

I changed the code to declare instance references to `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` objects, and instantiated only new `SqlDependency` instances in the `RegisterForChanges()` method.

```
void RegisterForChanges()
{
  _sqlCommand.Notification = null;
  _sqlConnection.Open();
  SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(_sqlCommand);
  dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;
  _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or ExecuteReader and parse the results, etc
  _sqlConnection.Close();
}
```